# How to save data in array

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI



struct Person: Identifiable, Codable{
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var isFavorite: Bool
}

class People: ObservableObject{
    @Published var group = [Person]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(peopleData){
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "peopleKey")
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    init(){
        if let savedItems = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "peopleKey"),
           let decodedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Person].self, from: savedItems) {
            group = decodedItems
        } else {
            group = peopleData
        }
    }
    
    var peopleData: [Person] = [
        Person(name: "Bob", isFavorite: false),
        Person(name: "John", isFavorite: false),
        Person(name: "Kayle", isFavorite: false),
        Person(name: "Alise", isFavorite: false)
    ]
    
}
```

I am tryn to save a chance on array. But when I relaunch its not saved.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var model = People()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10){
            Text(model.group[0].name)
                .opacity(model.group[0].isFavorite ? 1:0)
            Button(model.group[0].isFavorite ? "Remove from favorite" : "add to favorites") {
                model.group[0].isFavorite.toggle()
                   }
        }
        }

    
    }

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I can toggle the isFavorite bool with button. But when I relaunch its not saved.
in the which part of this code I made a mistake and why its not working I can't figure out.

I tried a lot of way for save data in array but all attempts was failed.

Comment: Check the capitalization: “peopleKEY” vs. “peopleKey”

Comment: I change the "peopleKEY" to "peopleKey" but still same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

currently you are saving `peopleData`, where you should be saving `group`. So try using:

```
class People: ObservableObject{
    @Published var group = [Person]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(group){ // <-- here group
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "peopleKey")
            }
        }
    }
   // ...
```

Comment: Thank you thats fix my all problems and headaches.